# Automaticly reload chrome browser on changes of HTML, Javascript or CSS

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, web-development

I there a good extension to automatically reload the chrome browser on any change of HTML, Javascript or CSS ?

Comment: [LiveReload](https://livereload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) works for me. Current usage: Install Python -> `pip install livereload` -> `livereload path/to/code` -> http://127.0.0.1:35729/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Try [Luba Autoreload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/luba-autoreload/pbkdhjjigfmmodacjodghoioeglbmieo). It's the simplest and best extension in my opinion.
But relatively unknown for no reason.

Comment: Probably unknown due to its name..

Comment: Probably because it's glitchy and hasn't been updated in years, and because it breaks Chrome?